# Hopping text in md-autocomplete of angular material

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angular-material

I have the following angular material component:

```
<div flex>
    <md-autocomplete 
          md-selected-item="selectedSavedList"
          md-search-text="searchSavedList"
          md-search-text-change="savedListItemChange(searchText)"
          md-items="item in querySavedList(searchSavedList)"
          md-item-text="item.name"
          md-min-length="0"
          style="min-width: 300px;"
          placeholder="hellow">
            <md-item-template style="background-color:white;">
                <span class="select-title">
                <span> {{item.name}} </span>
          </span>
            </md-item-template>
    </md-autocomplete>
</div>
```

First, when i hover my mouse to the component, the placeholding text moves slightly to bottom. if mouse leaves the component, text moves again to its own place. After i click, after i select an item, it does exact the same movements. I use the component almost everywhere in my project and their only common thing is css files (thus no js-issue)

Is it known issue of material or is somewhere in my css causing it? If so, which parts can have influence on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of the problem was the changing `line-height` property (although it is not clear whether it is effected by another framework or not).

Assigning a line-height property to the input elements solves the problem.

e.g.

```
md-autocomplete input:not(.md-input) {
    line-height: 2.42857143;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, works good for me. Maybe its the browser or the code before? Did you wrap it with other flex or layout attributs?